# Change value of a particular key in array of dictionaries in SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nsmutablearray

Am new to swift and am using an array of multiple dictionaries. So i want to change the value of a particular key. Please guide me how to achieve it :

Values In Array :-
[
{
"Start":"2:00 AM",
"End":"2:00 AM"
},
{
"Start":"3:00 AM",
"End":"3:00 AM"
}
]

**To Do:- I want to change the value of key `Start` at index 1**

Code:-

```
var aEntry = NSMutableArray.init()

for (index, type) in self.aEntry.enumerated(){
 print("this is index value \(index)")
 print("this is type value \(type)")

 // Value of checkCurrentClickOfStart = 1
                                
    if index == Int(checkCurrentClickOfStart) {
        let (item, newValue) = (index, "\(strHour)")
        if 0 ..< self.aEntry.count ~= index {
                          
            (self.aEntry[index] as? NSMutableDictionary)?["Start"] = newValue
        }
    }
                
}
```

Comment: you can directly used as like **aEntry[Int(checkCurrentClickOfStart)]["Start"] = "\(strHour)"**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it says "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts"

Comment: @hemant-garg: ` if 0 ..< self.aEntry.count ~= index {` this check is useless, but other than that whats the issue with this code?

Comment: Stop using NS classes, use swift types instead

Comment: You can read about swift collection types in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) book

Answer (score 0):

First of all Use Array instead of NSMutableArray
See the example code below

```
 var yourArray = [["Start":"2:00 AM", "End":"2:00 AM"], ["Start":"3:00 AM", "End":"3:00 AM"]]
    
// Change the value of a key "Start" at Index 1
 yourArray[1].updateValue("2:50 AM", forKey: "Start")
```